# Find a string, replace with filename variable and identifier (R)

Tags: r, xml, xslt

I'm working with directories of xml documents. I want to insert a unique identifier attribute in certain nodes. For example, in a file named `news-1950.xml` I want to turn the first `<div>` into `<div idno="news-1950-001">`, the next `<div>` into `<div ido="news-1950-002">`, and so on.

The identifiers do not need to be sequential, but they do need to be unique.

I've tried xslt transformations using `generate-id()`, but this only works on one file at a time, and the random identifiers risk being repeated in another file--I have thousands of files to process.

In R, I can isolate the filename as a variable using a `gsub` function, but I don't see how to insert that variable into the capture group using regex. Similarly, I can use a counter, but I don't see how to insert that into a string of text.

Comment: An XSLT processor has no memory of previous transformations. If you have "thousands of files to process", you cannot assure a unique id across files unless you either (a) use a UUID or (b) use some external process to record the last used serial number and pass it as  a parameter to the next transformation or (c) transform all files at once (here you can use a serial number or `generate-id()`).

Comment: However, if the filename is unique, then you should have no problem using a concatenation of filename and either a serial number or `generate-id()` - provided that you are able to pass the filename as a parameter to the transformation.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of XSLT, you will need to pass in the file name (e.g. `news-1950`) as a global parameter e.g. top level `<xsl:param name="file-name"/>`, then you can write a template matching `div` elements and use `xsl:number` e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="div">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="index">
      <xsl:number level="any"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:attribute name="idno">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($file-name, $index)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a string-substitution (as opposed to XML-domain) method.

Assuming you either have read them into a list of `character` vectors, or can adapt the below such that instead of access `XMLs`, it *reads them in*, does the string change, then *writes them back out*.

For here, I'll use a named-list, where the names are the "file names".

```r
XMLs <- list("news-1950"='<xml><div><div idno="quux"><div><something></xml>',"news-1960"='<xml><div><div idno="foo"><something><div><div></xml>')
XMLs
# $`news-1950`
# [1] "<xml><div><div idno=\"quux\"><div><something></xml>"
# $`news-1960`
# [1] "<xml><div><div idno=\"foo\"><something><div><div></xml>"
```

We'll iterate over the names:

```r
for (nm in names(XMLs)) {
  # read in from file?
  gre <- gregexpr("<div>", XMLs[[nm]])
  mat <- regmatches(XMLs[[nm]], gre)[[1]]
  regmatches(XMLs[[nm]], gre) <-
    list(sprintf(sub(">$", ' idno="%s_%04i">', mat), nm, seq_along(mat)))
  # write back to file?
}
XMLs
# $`news-1950`
# [1] "<xml><div idno=\"news-1950_0001\"><div idno=\"quux\"><div idno=\"news-1950_0002\"><something></xml>"
# $`news-1960`
# [1] "<xml><div idno=\"news-1960_0001\"><div idno=\"foo\"><something><div idno=\"news-1960_0002\"><div idno=\"news-1960_0003\"></xml>"
```